# Cannot add/edit entity in hdbdd file

Tags: hana

I'm getting errors when add/edit entity in hdbdd.

The current entity is

```
Entity TaskHeader {
        key YearID: Integer;
};
```

I'm adding another key to it

```
Entity TaskHeader {
        key YearID: Integer;
        key SiteType: SString;
};
```

However, when I save and activate it, it generates error

```
ESH activation error: not supported type conversion: Not supported conversion from BigInt to Integer
```

But if I remove the entity, save and activate. There is no error.

I've dropped cascade the table as well and tried to add the entity again but same error. Even I try with different data type, it's still same error.

Why does this happen?

Thanks

Tri

Answer (score 0):

check linked objects

to achieve this you should "Get where used list " of your object in IDE or use SQL code below, because error not in current entity but in some linked object

```sql
SELECT BASE_SCHEMA_NAME, BASE_OBJECT_NAME, DEPENDENT_SCHEMA_NAME,DEPENDENT_OBJECT_NAME, DEPENDENT_OBJECT_TYPE
FROM "SYS"."OBJECT_DEPENDENCIES"
WHERE BASE_SCHEMA_NAME = 'YOUR_SCHEMA' /* <== Schema Name */
AND BASE_OBJECT_NAME = 'TaskHeader' /* <== Table Name */
```

Comment: Hi atul, I've checked linked objects by using your sql. However, there are no records against the sql statement.

Comment: so you still have described problem?

Comment: Yeah. It still occurs.